# ¿Como utilizar una misma variable para restar dependiendo cuando exista o no otra variable, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Actualmente me encuentro realizando unas validación y me encuentro en esta etapa:

```
var total_pagar = 6000;
console.log("HAY QUE REALIZAR LA RESTA");
                    if (monto_ingresado){
                        let resultado = total_pagar-monto_ingresado;
                        return resultado;
                    }
                    else{
                        let resultado = total_pagar-forma_pago;
                        return resultado;
                    }

                        console.log(resultado);//No imprime nada.

                    if (parseInt(resultado)<0){
                        console.log("Monto ingresado excede al total a pagar");
                    }
                    else{
                        if (parseInt(resultado) === 0){
                            console.log("Cubre la deuda");
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("HAY QUE LLENAR LA TABLA");
                        }
                    }
```

en alguno casos puede que venga la variable `monto_ingresado` o en otros casos puede que venga la variable `forma_pago` para ambos casos se debe realizar la resta que es almacenada en la variable `resultado` y continuar con las validaciones de `if (parseInt(resultado)<0)` pero no logro realizar dicha resta.

Muy agradecido por el apoyo.

Comment: Tal vez sea por tus `return`, sea cual sea la variable retornas del método (imagino que tienes eso dentro de un método) de modo que nunca llega a console.log(..) ni a las demás comprobaciones.

Comment: Efectivamente, estás haciendo el return en ambas condiciones por lo que nunca te va a llegar al console.log

Comment: Deberías también añadir un poco de información de cómo llamas a la función. De todas formas, quitando los return tampoco te va a funcionar porque el "scope" de resultado es relativo a los bloques donde la defines con let (el if y el else) por lo que al llegar a console.log(resultado); no va a saber qué es "resultado"